# No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Tags: bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, ssh-keys

I have created ssh key using the command `ssh keygen` and I have added the public key to my bitbucket account and then I have added the key to the ssh agent also, But when I tried to clone repo from bitbucket using sourceTree, I am getting the below Error.

```
Error: FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

and I know this is repeated question but those solution didn't worked for me, So please help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, It was my mistake actually,
SSH Client type was set to PuTTY/Plink in my SourceTree Settings, So I changed it to openSSH and now that issue is no more.
Sorry & Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this is not enough for me? I changed the SSH Client Type as you indicated, but I keep getting that error.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had the same problem and this fixed it quickly

Answer (score 3):

I am using SourceTree to access an enterprise GitHub server, and had the same issue all of a sudden start occurring to me even though it has been working fine for over a year and nothing had changed. Apparently, somehow my SSH Client Type was swapped to PuTTY/Plink. Switching it to openSSH again fixed the issue for me by going to Tools -> Options -> General -> then selecting OpenSSH as the SSH Client under the SSH Client Configuration section.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the SSH Client type to openSSH in Source Tree - tools -> Options -> General solved this error for me.

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Answer (score 1):

(I posted the following to [atlassian.com bug report](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-8295?error=login_required&error_description=Login%20required&state=363c8565-bfcc-47ec-92bf-bc3cc50a266f))

We had the same issue. We noticed that the Pageant (in the icon tray) would not start.

For us it appears that our antivirus was blocking it somehow. Thus we do the following:

1. disabled the antivirus
2. uninstall SourceTree (SourcetreeEnterpriseSetup_3.4.6.msi)
3. installed SourceTree (SourceTreeSetup-3.4.6.exe)
4. reconfigured SourceTree
5. We noticed that Pageant was now running and ssh calls worked.
6. Reenabled the antivirus.

So far so good.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was getting same error but the "pageant" program installed was very very old, but worked after updating it (via the putty installer). Credit to https://superuser.com/users/106302/fabian @ https://superuser.com/a/404286/658383